# How to inform a ViewModel that its collectionSource was changed(add, update or delete) from another viewModel in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

If i have a viewmodel for adding new item and another viewmodel for displaying all or filtered items (the second viewmodel's view must always reflect any changes in the collection source), should the change be communicated from viewmodel to viewmodel directly, or viewmodel to repository to second viewmodel?

I tried the following

```
public class DataAccess //my repository
{
    public DataAccess()
    {
        var ctx = new MyDbContext();
    }
    public void AddNewItem(Item item)
    {
        ctx.items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> GetAllItems()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Item>(ctx.items.ToList());
    }
```

Here's my first ViewModel

```
public class ItemsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        DataAccess dt = new DataAccess();
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(dt.GetAllItems());
    }
    //AllItems is bound to datagrid
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _allItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems
    {
        get {return _allItems;}
        set {_allItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }
    //command to load the form for adding new item then the method below
    //I passed AllItems into the constructor
    //I think I can also pass AllItems using Messenger, but I haven't tried it yet
    void LoadNewItemForm()
    {
        NewItemView view = new NewItemView(){DataContext = new NewItemViewModel(AllItems)};
        view.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Here's the second viewmodel

```
public class AddNewItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public AddNewItemViewModel(ObservableCollection<Item> allItems)
    {
        DataAccess dt = new DataAccess();
        _allItems = allItems;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _allItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems
    {
        get {return _allItems;}
        set {_allItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }
    //Here's the AddNewItem method
    public void SaveNewItem()
    {
        Item newitem = new Item(){ ..... };
        dt.AddNewItem(item);

        //Now is this change in AllItems here supposed to reflect in the allItems passed via constructor (will this reflect in the first ViewModel)
        AllItems.Add(newitem);
    }
```

I've tried creating the `AllItems` property in the repository (`DataAccess class`) so that this `AllItems` property will be the one to be returned in the call for `GetAllItems()` and also it is in the repository where I'll call `AllItems.Add(something)` or `AllItems.Remove(something)`. Still, change in this does not reflect in the first viewModel.

Comment: *"change in this does not reflect in the first viewModel."* -- What do you mean by "reflect"? What program behavior did you hope to see, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: *"this AllItems property will be the one to be returned in the call for GetAllItems()"* -- `GetAllItems()` returns a new, different collection object on each call.

Comment: Is this really the code you're trying? The `dt` variable is declared in the AddNewItemViewModel constructor, but you're trying to reference it in the `SaveNewItem()` method.

Comment: I've solved this problem before by raising events from the data/service layer - DataAccess in your case - when a CRUD operation is committed. The view model can listen to these events and update the ObservableCollection appropriately.

Comment: @SeeSharpCode oh I actually do it like this 'DataAccess dt;' then in the constructor 'dt = new DataAccess()'. Anyway, should i do that in the SaveNewItem() method?

Comment: @SeeSharpCode and can I see some code in how you solved this kind of problem before?

Comment: @Ed I expect the datagrid bound to AllItems in first viewModel to show the new item instantly as soon as i save thew new item in second viewmodel

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Can we see the XAML for the datagrid bound to AllItems? How are you setting the DataContext in that XAML? I'd suggest putting a breakpoint in the `ItemsViewModel` constructor to make sure you're not creating two of them somehow -- that's a very common cause of mysteries like this.

Comment: By the way, you are calling a lot of redundant constructors in `DataAccess.GetAllItems()` and in the code that calls it: First you create a new list for some reason, then you pass that to the ObservableCollection constructor, return that, and then the caller creates *another* new ObservableCollection. The redundancy looks harmless to me, but it suggests that there may be other things going on in your code that you don't fully understand.

Comment: I went back to Rob Miles' C# Programming Yellow Book and realized that I forgot all about the concepts of objects and references. How stupid of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using events to inform the view models when the data changes.

The data layer:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private readonly MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();

    public event EventHandler<DataChangedEventArgs> ItemsChanged;

    public void AddNewItem(Item item)
    {
        ctx.Items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        RaiseItemsChanged(new DataChangedEventArgs(DataAction.Added, item));
    }

    public List<Item> GetAllItems()
    {
        return ctx.Items.ToList();
    }

    public void RaiseItemsChanged(DataChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ItemsChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

The event args:

```
public enum DataAction
{
    Added,
    Deleted
}

public class DataChangedEventArgs
{
    public DataAction DataAction { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public DataChangedEventArgs(DataAction dataAction, Item item)
    {
        DataAction = dataAction;
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

The first view model:

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{
    private readonly DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(dataAccess.GetAllItems());

        dataAccess.ItemsChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.DataAction == DataAction.Added)
                AllItems.Add(eventArgs.Item);
            else
                AllItems.Remove(eventArgs.Item);
        };
    }
}
```

This helps separate concerns because the `AddNewItemViewModel` can now add an item without worrying about updating `ItemsViewModel`. You could also take a lazier approach and handle any event by clearing and repopulating the `ObservableCollection<Item>`.

Comment: thanks! This surely helps me. I actually fixed this problem already by telling my `MainViewModel` to recall the `ItemsViewModel` into `MainView`'s `ContentControl` but it's forced to query again from the database which I don't think is very efficient especially if I have a lot of data.
So I'll definitely use this. How about if an item is edited using another viewModel (`EditItemViewModel`)? From `ItemsViewModel` I will pass an item to `EditItemViewModel`, edit some Item's properties, then what should the `ItemsViewModel` do to `AllItems` if an `Edited` event is fired?

Comment: For updating, should I just use your "lazier approach"?
Inform my ItemsViewModel that something is edited, and in ItemsViewModel

    `if (eventArgs.DataAction == DataAction.Edited)
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Items>(dataAccess.GetAllItems());`

Comment: or `if (eventArgs.DataAction == DataAction.Edited)

AllItems.Clear();
foreach (var item in dataAccess.GetAllItems())
{ AllItems.Add(item); }`

Comment: Anyway, do the ViewModels really need to share a `DataAccess` instance? Without it, the datagrid does not show the newly added item. Also, when I try to delete that newly added item, it gives me an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`. I solved it again by creating a new instance of `context` for every methods in the `DataAccess` class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `Item` implements INotifyPropertyChanged, then you could pass it to `EditItemViewModel`, edit it, and the changes should be reflected in `ItemsViewModel` without raising an event.

Comment: Yes, the view models will need to share an instance of `DataAccess` for the event to work properly. You could use a static event, but that comes with overhead. Using dependency injection to inject `DataAccess` into the view models that need it should work fine.

Comment: Do you understand that you've just added a redundant layer to raise duplicate events to the ones that the ObservableCollection is already raising?

Comment: Changes to the `DbContext` and the `ObservableCollection` occur in different contexts, so I don't see the event as a duplicate.

Comment: I also don't want to create and update the AllItems observableCollection in the DataAccess layer so I think this is the best way to avoid that. Or I could use MVVM Light's Messenger class.